# Disable the Close Button until the user clicks on the LogOff MenuItem

Tags: c#

I am creating an application for Library Management Systems.

I want to disable the close button initially and enable it once the user clicks on the menu 
item logoff.

Is there any way I could accomplish this functionality in my application?

I tried using the following code in the formClosing event but it is not working out.

```
  private void frmLibrary_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)

  {

  e.Cancel = false;

  if (checkLogOff == false)

  {

  MessageBox.Show("Please Log Off before closing the Application");

  e.Cancel = false;

  this.ControlBox = false;

  return;

  }

  else

  {

  this.ControlBox = true;

  e.Cancel = true;

  }

  }
```

The value of checkLogOff Variable is set as follows:

```
  public bool checkLogOff = false;

  private void logOffToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

  {

  checkLogOff = true;

  /*Code to update the logoff users in the database*/

  }
```

When executing the application if I dont click on the LogOff menu item I am getting the dialog box but immediately after I press the OK Button in the Message Box the Application closes. But I dont want to allow the user to close the application before clicking on the LogOff MenuItem.

Please help me out in accomplishing this task.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Um, why not just log people off when they close the form?  Or isn't that hard enough?

Answer (score 1):

I would not fiddle with the `ControlBox` property for this purpose, since it also removes the Maximize and Minimize buttons. The main issue with your code is that you should set `Cancel` to `true` in `FormClosing` to prevent the form from being closed. I think your code can be reduced to this, and still achieve what you want (given that we don't touch `ControlBox`):

```
private void frmLibrary_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = !checkLogOff;
    if (e.Cancel)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Log Off before closing the Application");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Now it is working fine!
Even your answer is correct but I can mark only one persons answer as the correct answer so sorry. Anyways thanks a lot for your prompt help!

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Please Log Off before closing the Application");
e.Cancel = false;
this.ControlBox = false;
return;
```

To this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Please Log Off before closing the Application");
e.Cancel = true;
this.ControlBox = false;
return;
```

You aren't canceling the form load.

Answer (score 0):

When checkLogOff == false, you want to cancel the event, so you should set e.Cancel to True,
and to False when checkLogOff == true.

Answer (score 0):

You inverted the setting of e.Cancel

it must be:

```
e.Cancel = true;
```

when you need to prevent the application from closing.

==>

```
  private void frmLibrary_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
  {
      e.Cancel = false;
      if (checkLogOff == false)
      {
          MessageBox.Show("Please Log Off before closing the Application");
          e.Cancel = true; // <--
          this.ControlBox = false;
          return;
      }
      else
      {
          this.ControlBox = true;
          e.Cancel = false; // <--
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that is not the answer you seek, but telling a user to go to another menue item to log of, if he just wants to close the application is cubersome.

Why tell him he needs to log off? Cant you just call the Logoff function on his behalf, or display a dialog that asks if he wants to log off?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions I have included the coding for LogOff in a separate method and it is called automatically when the user clicks on the close button of the form.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you do a test against e.CloseReason, and only perform your cancel-logic if it's a user closing action, otherwise your application *will* prevent a system shutdown, and an 'End this task now' dialog isn't a good impression on your users.